# How to Change the Length of a Sequence Using Linear Projection In PyTorch?

Tags: deep-learning, python, pytorch, speech-synthesis

I was trying to reproduce a voice conversion model using PyTorch and I had difficulty implementing a module called PBTC (Parallel Bank of Transposed Convlutions), used in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.12197.pdf. As in the paper, it consists of several parallel branches with transposed convlution followed by a linear projection.

[image]

The input to this module is a sequence of f0 (fundamental frequency) embeddings with shape `[B, T, L]`. Basically we want it to pass through the PBTC module and get a new sequence with shape `[B, T, F]`.

As shown in the figure, it first passes through a transposed convolution and get a sequence with shape `[B, t', F]`. Then it passes through a linear projection and get a sequence with shape `[B, T, F]`.

But the thing is how to define such linear projection? As in the figure, `t'` is computed using `t`, dilation `dil` and kernel size `k`, where `t` should be the length of input sequence, `T`. But we don't exactly know what `t` is since the length of input sequence varies among different data point. So should I fix the input length, truncating or padding the raw input sequence to fit this length? But this does't seem to make sense...

My implementation of PBTC module is as follow:

```
class PBTC(nn.Module):
    """
    Parallel Bank of Transposed Convolutions
    Reference:
    https://www.isca-speech.org/archive/pdfs/interspeech_2020/webber20_interspeech.pdf
    https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.12197.pdf
    """

    def __init__(self,
                 in_channels,
                 out_channels,
                 input_length,
                 output_length,
                 kernel_size=50,
                 num_branches=10):
        super(PBTC, self).__init__()
        self.in_channels = in_channels
        self.out_channels = out_channels
        self.input_length = input_length
        self.output_length = output_length
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.num_branches = num_branches

        self.branches = nn.ModuleList()

        for dilation in range(1, 2 * num_branches, 2):
            # t' = (t-1) + dil * (k-1) + 1
            input_length_prime = (input_length - 1) + dilation * (self.kernel_size - 1) + 1
            self.branches.append(
                nn.Sequential(
                    # ConvTranspose1D(num_filters, stride, dilation)
                    nn.ConvTranspose1d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=50, stride=1, dilation=dilation),
                    nn.Linear(in_features=input_length_prime, out_features=output_length),
                    nn.ReLU()
                )
            )

    def forward(self, seq):
        # seq: [B, N, L]
        seq = seq.permute(0, 2, 1)  # [B, L, N]
        encoded_seq = torch.zeros((seq.size(0), self.out_channels, seq.size(-1)))  # B, F, N]
        for branch in self.branches:
            encoded_seq += branch(seq)
        encoded_seq = encoded_seq.permute(0, 2, 1)  # [B, N, F]

        return encoded_seq
```

I really appriciate it if anyone could help me!

Comment: I also encountered the same problem, did you solve it?